# Changing background color of treeview node according to the database value

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I'm trying to get a count of rows from the SQL query and if the return value is !=0, I want to change the back color of my treeview1 Node08. I have tried this,but it won't work.

Please help me with this

```
private void frm_Main_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
          bl_DataLoading countobj = new bl_DataLoading();
          DataTable countdt = new DataTable();
          countdt = countobj.Count_Requests();

          if (countdt.Rows.Count!=0)
          {
              treeView1.Nodes["Node8"].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
          }
}
```

Comment: `var node = treeView1.Nodes.Find("Node8", true).FirstOrDefault(); if (node != null) node.BackColor = Color.Red;`. Does `countobj.Count_Requests()` return a DataTable? If so, do you need to assign it to another DataTable there? If not, then...

Comment: Hi @Jimi > Data Table carries a count of rows. What I'm doing is if datatable rows count is not equal to zero. then color this node.

Comment: My question was: what is this `countobj.Count_Requests()`? Is it a DataTable? Since you're assigning this object to a DataTable, that's what it looks like. But then, why don't you use `countobj.Count_Requests().Rows.Count`?

Comment: oh ! That's saved my day. Thank you so much @Jimi . It worked as i expected.